# Automate Date Picker via removeAttribute('readonly') with Gauge / Taiko

Tags: javascript, getgauge

Apologies if this question has already been asked / answered.

I'm keen to automate a date picker by removing the readonly attribute on the field and passing the date directly into it.

I know this is possible with Selenium, iMacros and other similar tools.  For Example [here](https://medium.com/@priyank.it/problem-statement-26e294430e0c):

```js
@Test  
public void CalendarTest()      
{  
   WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();   
          
   // Creating JavascriptExecutor interface object Type casting  
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  
          
   // Launching the Site.              driver.get("http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/components_date_time_pickers.html");   
          
  WebElement datePicker = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='form-control'])[11]"));          
          
  // Need to remove readonly HTML attribute  
  js.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[11].removeAttribute('readonly');", datePicker);
          
  // Enter Date directly into the field
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='form-control'])[11]")).sendKeys("03-05-2019");      
  }
```

However, cannot achieve the same result in Gauge/Taiko using JavaScript.

I'm relatively new to Taiko, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to be working in my case:

```
evaluate(textBox({name:"fieldName"}), (element) => element.setAttribute("value", "01-01-2020"))
```